# How to load datagrid base in parent datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have this 2 datagrid, on selectionchanged in first datagrid it will load the data base in the id i passed in second datagrid

this is the code from first datagrid in selectionchanged event

```
private void equipmentDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var row_list = (Equipment)equipmentDataGrid.SelectedItem;
            var inspectionContent = new InspectionContent();

            inspectionContent.PassingValue(row_list.ID);


        }
        catch {
        }
    }
```

InspectionContent is the another usercontrol w/c contains the second datagrid. i passed a id value to load the data in second datagrid, my problem was the loading part is not called in the constructor, why is it the data in second datagrid is not loading?

[image: wpfimg]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the event args if you want to proceed in this way with the code behind

```
DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
if  (sender != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0) {
  var row = e.AddedItems[0] as Equipment;
  if (row != null)
    {
            inspectionContent.PassingValue(row.ID);
```

Alternatively, for the future,  you may want to study the MVVM approach that is based  on property binding ...

Please note also that your try/catch is very bad, since it silently discard any exception, at least track the error in debug

```
catch (Exception exc) {
    Debug.WriteLine (exc.Message + exc.StackTrace);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates a *new* instance of the `InspectionContent` UserControl:

```
var inspectionContent = new InspectionContent();
```

You want to call the PassingValue of the already created instance that you see on the screen.

Give it a name ("uc" in the below sample) in your XAML markup:

```
<local:InspectionContent x:Name="uc" ...>
```

...and access it using this name in the event handler:

```
private void equipmentDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var row_list = (Equipment)equipmentDataGrid.SelectedItem;
    uc.PassingValue(row_list.ID);
}
```